# MySQL Database Join Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Please could someone advise how to write a mySQL query for the result below based on Table A and Table B information.

```
Table A
=======

ID | Product
------------
1  | A
2  | B
3  | C

Table B
=======

ID | Link | Extra Field | Extra Value
-------------------------------------
1  |  1   | Tax         | Yes
2  |  1   | Photo       | No
3  |  2   | Tax         | Yes
4  |  2   | Photo       | Yes
5  |  3   | Tax         | No
6  |  3   | Photo       | Yes

Result
======

Product | Tax | Photo
---------------------
A       | Yes | No
B       | Yes | Yes
C       | No  | Yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is a `join` and `group by` query, with conditional aggregation.

```
select a.product,
       max(case when field1 = 'tax' then field2 end) as tax,
       max(case when field1 = 'photo' then field2 end) as photo
from a join
     b
     on a.id = b.link
group by a.product;
```